# setVisible() before executing code in eclipse SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, progress-bar, swt

I want to set a `ProgressBar` visible via a `SelectionListener` before some code is executed.
However, the code will be executed but the `ProgressBar` remains invisible.

The code looks as follows:

```
...
progressBar().setVisible(true);
parseFile(...);
...

public void parseFile(File file) {
    System.out.println("Parsing File: " + file);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        File fileToWrite = new File(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "anonym_"
                + file.getName());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWrite));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(replacements.getSubstitutedText(line));
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`parseFile()` will be executed but `setVisible` won't. If i remove `parseFile()`, `setVisible` will be executed.

How can I execute `doSth()` AFTER setting the progressBar visible?

Full code:

Class Anonymous2:

```
package main;

import view.MainView;

public class Anonymous2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new MainView().open();
    }
}
```

Class MainView:

```
package view;

import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

import controller.MainViewController;

public class MainView {

protected Shell shlAnonymous;
private List list;
private Table table;
private TableViewer tableViewer;
private TableEditor editor;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

public Table getTable() {
    return table;
}
public TableViewer getTableViewer() {
    return tableViewer;
}
public Shell getShell() {
    return shlAnonymous;
}
public TableEditor getEditor() {
    return editor;
}
public ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
    return progressBar;
}

/**
 * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();

    shlAnonymous = new Shell();

    shlAnonymous.setSize(800, 404);
    shlAnonymous.setText("Anonymous");
    shlAnonymous.setLayout(new FormLayout());

    createContents();

    shlAnonymous.open();
    shlAnonymous.layout();

    while (!shlAnonymous.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    MainViewController controller = new MainViewController(this);

    Label lblHeader = new Label(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    FormData fd_lblHeader = new FormData();
    fd_lblHeader.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_lblHeader.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    lblHeader.setLayoutData(fd_lblHeader);
    lblHeader.setText("Files to Replace");

    Button btnQuit = new Button(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    btnQuit.addSelectionListener(controller);
    FormData fd_btnQuit = new FormData();
    fd_btnQuit.left = new FormAttachment(100, -106);
    fd_btnQuit.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    fd_btnQuit.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    btnQuit.setLayoutData(fd_btnQuit);
    btnQuit.setText("Quit");
    btnQuit.setData("name", "quit");

    Button btnAnon = new Button(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    btnAnon.addSelectionListener(controller);
    FormData fd_btnAnon = new FormData();
    fd_btnAnon.right = new FormAttachment(btnQuit, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_btnAnon.bottom = new FormAttachment(btnQuit, -6);
    fd_btnAnon.left = new FormAttachment(btnQuit, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    btnAnon.setLayoutData(fd_btnAnon);
    btnAnon.setText("Replace");
    btnAnon.setData("name", "anon");

    Button btnAdd = new Button(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    btnAdd.addSelectionListener(controller);
    FormData fd_btnAdd = new FormData();
    fd_btnAdd.right = new FormAttachment(0, 106);
    fd_btnAdd.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    fd_btnAdd.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    btnAdd.setLayoutData(fd_btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setText("Add");
    btnAdd.setData("name", "add");

    Button btnDelete = new Button(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    btnDelete.addSelectionListener(controller);
    FormData fd_btnDelete = new FormData();
    fd_btnDelete.right = new FormAttachment(btnAdd, 102, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_btnDelete.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
    fd_btnDelete.left = new FormAttachment(btnAdd, 6);
    btnDelete.setLayoutData(fd_btnDelete);
    btnDelete.setText("Delete");
    btnDelete.setData("name", "delete");

    list = new List(shlAnonymous, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
    list.addKeyListener(controller);
    FormData fd_list = new FormData();
    fd_list.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_list.bottom = new FormAttachment(btnAnon, 0, SWT.BOTTOM);
    fd_list.top = new FormAttachment(lblHeader, 6);
    list.setLayoutData(fd_list);

    table = new Table(shlAnonymous, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    fd_list.right = new FormAttachment(table, -6);
    FormData fd_table = new FormData();
    fd_table.right = new FormAttachment(btnAnon, -22);
    fd_table.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, -41);
    fd_table.top = new FormAttachment(0, 31);
    fd_table.left = new FormAttachment(0, 336);
    table.setLayoutData(fd_table);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    tableViewer = new TableViewer(table);
    tableViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnTerm = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnTerm.setWidth(160);
    tblclmnTerm.setText("Term");

    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    tableItem.setText("");

    TableColumn tblclmnSubstitution = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnSubstitution.setWidth(156);
    tblclmnSubstitution.setText("Replace With");

    progressBar = new ProgressBar(shlAnonymous, SWT.NONE);
    FormData fd_progressBar = new FormData();
    fd_progressBar.right = new FormAttachment(table, 0, SWT.RIGHT);
    fd_progressBar.bottom = new FormAttachment(btnQuit, 0, SWT.BOTTOM);
    fd_progressBar.left = new FormAttachment(btnDelete, 6);
    progressBar.setLayoutData(fd_progressBar);
    progressBar.setMinimum(0);
    progressBar.setVisible(false);
}

public void addListItem(String item) {
    list.add(item);
}

public void addListItems(String rootFolder, String[] items) {
    for (String item : items) {
        addListItem(rootFolder + File.separator + item);
    }
}

public File[] getFilesToParse() {
    File[] files = new File[list.getItemCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getItemCount(); i++) {
        files[i] = new File(list.getItem(i));
    }
    return files;
}
}
```

Class MainViewController:

```
package controller;

import model.Parser;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;

import view.MainView;

public class MainViewController implements SelectionListener, KeyListener {

private MainView mainView;

public MainViewController(MainView mainView) {
    this.mainView = mainView;
}

@Override
public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
    processSelectionEvent(arg0);
}

@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
    processSelectionEvent(arg0);
}

private void processSelectionEvent(SelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof Button) {
        Button button = (Button)e.getSource();
        if (button.getData("name").equals("quit")) {
        } else if (button.getData("name").equals("anon")) {


            mainView.getProgressBar().setVisible(true);
            Parser parser = new Parser();
            parser.parseFiles(mainView.getFilesToParse());


        } else if (button.getData("name").equals("add")) {
            FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(mainView.getShell(), SWT.MULTI);
            fileDialog.setText("Dateien wählen");
            fileDialog.open();
            mainView.addListItems(fileDialog.getFilterPath(), fileDialog.getFileNames());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {}


}
```

Class Parser:

```
package model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Parser {

public boolean parseFile(File file) {
    System.out.println("Parsing File: " + file);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
        File fileToWrite = new File(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "anonym_"
                + file.getName());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWrite));
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            bw.write(line);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(line);
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void parseFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        parseFile(file);
    }
}
}
```

I've cut a lot of code but the problem still remains.

The problematic lines are lines 40-42 in class Parser. Line 40 is executed AFTER lines 41-42.

Some explanations:
The progressBar becomes visible AFTER the parser finished working. To see the problem I suggest to add a sufficiently large number of files (add-Button) so that the parser can work (replace-Button) for at least 1 second. The progressBar will be visible after one second and should be visible immediately after clicking the button.

Comment: please, give more info about what does `doSth()` do.

Comment: @user1597957 - Its hard to tell the problem from your code snippet. I have a simple app which is working as your desired result. It would help if you could provide an executable piece of code.

Comment: Agreed, try to put up an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem. We can then "fix" the SSCCE and tell you, what was wrong and how you should fix it.

Comment: Ok, I added code of all 4 classes needed to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run your parser in the UI Thread. While your code is parsing swt has no chance to repaint your Progressbar. So the Progressbar is painted after parsing is finished. You should parse in a separate thread and update the Progressbar from this Thread with Display.asyncExec(). See http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet56.java for an example how to do this.